# How to Map Dictionary<int, Product> and List<ProductDto> using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this code and am wondering how to create the map configuration for this

```
public Product{ int ProductId, string ProductName}

public ProductDto { int ProductId, string ProductName}

_mapper.Map<Dictionary<int, Product>, List<ProductDto >>(product);
```

For now this is what I have and am tinkering with LINQ to solve this issue.

```
public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Dictionary<int, Product>, List<ProductDto>>()
            .ForMember(dest => new List(){ new ProductDto(){}}, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Values.))
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a mapping profile from `Dictionary<int, Product>` to `List<ProductDto>` in this case. A `Dictionary<K, V>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` so if you configure the conversion from  `KeyValuePair<int, Product>` to `ProductDto`, AutoMapper will handle the rest.

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();

CreateMap<KeyValuePair<int, Product>, ProductDto>()
    .ConstructUsing((pair, context) => context.Mapper.Map<Product, ProductDto>(pair.Value));
```

Comment: Im trying this. I'll get back to you if it works.